# Aiohttp not working with (free) http proxy?

Tags: python, http, proxy, aiohttp, http-proxy

I have the following code with free proxies that can visit Google successfully.

```py
proxies = {
    'http': '141.148.63.29:80'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.54'
}

url = "https://www.google.com/"

# snippet inside async function
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
    async with session.get(url=url, proxy=proxies['http'], ssl=False) as resp:
        print(resp.url, resp.status)
```

This will raise errors

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\test_aiohttp_proxy.py", line 30, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "...\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "...\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "...\test_aiohttp_proxy.py", line 27, in main
    async with session.get(url=url, proxy=proxies['http'], ssl=False) as resp:
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1194, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 578, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 909, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_proxy_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1250, in _create_proxy_connection
    proxy_req = ClientRequest(
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.update_host(url)
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 402, in update_host
    raise InvalidURL(url)
aiohttp.client_exceptions.InvalidURL: 141.148.63.29:80
```

But with same URL and proxy, the response can be received almost instantly with `requests` library.

```py
resp = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)

print(resp.url, resp.status_code)  # 200
```

When I remove the proxy keyword arg for aiohttp, it can also go through instantly. But with the proxy, it will always fail. And this is HTTP proxy not https so I have no idea why it does this.

btw: I try to set the policy for event loop from proactor to selector but it does not help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: URL. Try `'http://141.148.63.29:80'`